# How to log if an environment variable is unset?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, scripting

How can I write a shell script that checks for an environment variable and writes to a log file if the variable is unset?

Also, if the file name pointed by env variable doesn't exist, how to create it?

Comment: also asked in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7817267/7552)

Comment: Thanks for copying my edit and [cross-posting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting) it on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817267/how-to-log-if-an-environment-variable-is-unset)...anyway, you accepted an answer there and not here, so I'm going to close this version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An environment variable is one that is exported to subprocesses.
This script, yet to adapt to your need, could be of help. It uses the `${var:?word}` syntax, with and without `:` to determine the result:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset=0
null=0

if ! sh -c 'echo ${var?}' >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
   unset=1
elif ! sh -c 'echo ${var:?}' >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
   null=1
fi

echo "unset = $unset"
echo "null  = $null"
```

Comment: *@enzo:* An excellent clear answer which addresses the *unset* issue very well, and deals the associated *script abort* (+1).. I really needed something like this today; thanks.. It seems that I must first export the var in question (makes sense), and whether it is set or not, it is still detected appropriately in the sub-shell. very nice! ..One point of note is that is isn't possible to export arrays, (which is specifically what I was after :) but for non-array vars, it will definitely come in handy.. The method handles arrays in the current process, but will abort when var is not set/null.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you rightly,

`env | grep -q ^$VAR && logger -t varlogger "var is unset"`

`test -f $VAR || touch $VAR`

Comment: You'll want to grep for `^$VAR=` since just `^$VAR` can match several variables that start with the same thing.

You can also just `test $VAR && logger...`.